# iOS user data storage dilemma

Tags: ios, objective-c, keychain

I am new to Xcode and was trying to create a iOS app with a signup screen which would save user credentials on a MySQL server.

I wanted to know if that is the best approach as further in the application I would create events which other app users could join in on.

I was told that keychain might help but I'm not sure if it will be able to show the events to other app users.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please be a little more clear with your question. You cannot run a MySQL server in the iPhone, so i'm guessing it means you are communicating with a server API? if so, the keychain is only used to store the credentials locally on the device, not the server. When you mention "Other app users", you mean on the same device or on different devices?

Comment: Sorry if i wasn't clear, yes I am planning to store user credentials on a server (don't know how but i think it should work), the keychain i believe will be used for auto logins after the first one (as you mentioned they are stored locally) and other app users is for users who have the app on different devices. So just wanted to know if the server is the best option for storing client credentials and event data (events are created by the users) or if there is a better option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best thing for you sounds like it would be Firebase

Take a look, its free for up to a certain server size, you would be able to communicate between devices in real time (the events you were talking about).
There is also a lot of support online & on youtube.

https://firebase.google.com

Comment: thanks a lot for the info, this clears a lot of stuff for me.

Comment: No problem my friend :)